# Is it possible to add noise to the picture using Jimp in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot in Discord, to mostly goof. 
I decided to create a "deep-fry" command:

```
// stuff here
function deepfry(link) {
  var pixelValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2 + 2)
    Jimp.read(link)
    .then(image => {
      image
      .pixelate(pixelValue)
      .contrast(0.95)
      .write('./images/deepfry.png')
      message.channel.send({
        files: [
          './images/deepfry.png'
        ]
      })
    })
}
```

I noticed that, in comparision with other deep-fried images, its missing some noise. I couldn't find anything about applying it (well, using Jimp), any ideas on how could i apply some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familliar with Jimp, but from reading the docs you could try some of the following;

```
image.posterize( n );
image.sepia();
```

Comment: Posterize worked splendid! Sepia didn't really do it, but using posterize at about 8 worked great. Thanks!

Comment: @loib Glad I could help! Please make sure to set my answer as the solution so other people know this question has been answered!